# How to hide OCG (Optional Content Group) objects when rendering a pdf page with CoreGraphics

Tags: pdf, core-graphics

I wonder if there a way to disable/hide OCGs object when rendering a pdf gage with:

```
CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);
```

Is it possible to remove OCG objects using page reference? Or set their scale to 0, or change color to transparent etc.?

Comment: Well, looking for a possibility to modify pdf content on the fly, I came a cross this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31497910/cgpdf-where-are-the-setters . So it looks like CGPDF API can be only used for readonly access. The workaround would be to parse PDF document, find OCG objects and remove them in the initial file... Any other ideas?

Comment: Striping the pdf objects in the initial file is not that easy. I ended up with iterating over all pdf objects, checking their dictionaries to find out the object type: OCG and OCMD. Afterwards I marked these objects as deleted and created the corresponding pdf trailer for them.